# How to optimize my JS code in terms of complexity

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays:

```
user = [
  { id: 33, first_name: 'Alex', last_name: 'Shelly' },
  { id: 23, first_name: 'Mike', last_name: 'Marley' }
]

selectedNotes = [
  { employee_id: 33, notes: 'test' },
  { employee_id: 109, notes: 'test1' }
]
```

I am trying to find the `firstname` and `lastname` of the user whose `id` matches with the `employee_id` in the `selectedNotes` array. (e.g. Alex Shelly in the above case).

What I have:

```
for (let i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < selectedNotes.length; j++) {
    if (user[i].id == selectedNotes[j].employee_id) {
      selectedNotes.splice(j, 0, {
        by_name: user[i].first_name + ' ' + user[i].last_name
      }); // adding a new property in the array if the id matches
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this in terms of optimization?

Comment: You're inserting into `selectedNotes` while looping over it... that means *trouble*. Specifically in this case, it may work, but if you happen to insert an item that satisfies the adding condition... that's an infinite loop for you.

Comment: Yes - map the index - or use the id as index O(1): {[id]: value}

Comment: I understand you have a list of users, but if you index the maps accordingly, you will have O(N) runtime to build the map and then instant access from then on out.

Comment: you could always use a forEach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do a `map()` and an `Object.assign()`

```js
const user = [{
    id: 33,
    first_name: "Alex",
    last_name: "Shelly"
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    first_name: "Mike",
    last_name: "Marley"
  }
]

const selectedNotes = [{
  employee_id: 33,
  notes: 'test'
}, {
  employee_id: 109,
  notes: 'test1'
}]

// use map() to iterate over selectedNotes, and for each value
// in selectedNotes assign the values of an object from user,
// where we get the values by filtering the user array for the
// id of the current element in the iteration of selectedNotes

// TL;DR: run over selectedNotes, filter for the id value in
// user and add the resulting object's key-value pairs to the
// actual selectedNotes item
const selected = selectedNotes.map(e => Object.assign(e, user.filter(el => el.id === e.employee_id)[0]))

// output the resulting array of objects
console.log(selected)
```

Now you have all the data in one array of objects, so you only have to filter it for the value you look for.

References:

`Array.prototype.map()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

`Object.assign()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: .find() would be more cost effective than .filter()[0]

Comment: You're hiding the loops behind `map` and `filter`, how is that better in terms of optimization? Even worse, you're using `Object.assign` (which mutates its first argument) in `map`.

Comment: @hugo The question was about optimizing wrt code complexity, not performance

Comment: **.find()** is shorter than **.filter()[0]** - true, thank you. If performance optimization was the question, then I'd stick with **for(i++)** (or **for(i--)**), as these are the fastest (look here: https://medium.com/@muka.gergely/how-i-optimized-javascript-loops-in-my-app-261e03a6be89). Then (if we are talking about really large arrays) maybe Duff's Device could come into play. But thanks anyway for the opinions. :)

Comment: @MTCoster I understood *complexity* it as "time/space complexity" rather than "number of written instructions". Please ignore the first part of my comment if that was not what was meant.

Comment: @hugo and this discussion gave me an idea to really test out the performance of these different solutions - and maybe publish the results. It's a real life challenge. So many levels of optimization! :)

Comment: @muka.gergely Sorry for bestowing this upon you!

Comment: @muka.gergely Besides ranting about perf, I had also pointed out a dubious use of `Object.assign`... Your solution mutates `selectedNotes`; s items, which is probably undesired.

Comment: @hugo yep, I noticed that "mutation" concern. I just saw OP doing this, and thought it wasn't a problem in this case. I'll test if it's faster than creating a copy and returning that.

Comment: @muka.gergely I sure *hope* it's faster! Yeah OP was doing something very strange with his array... that also looked like a mistake :shrug:

Comment: @hugo I did a performance check: **for(i--)** is the fastest by far - without `Object.assign()`. Testing results: https://jsperf.com/filter-or-find-stackoverflow/1

Comment: @muka.gergely nice! makes sense tho. indexing the keys would be even faster.

Comment: @hugo what do you mean by “indexing the keys” here?

Comment: @muka.gergely I mean doing some kind of hash-map like a few other answers suggest (either using the plain-object key-value system, or using a Map)

Comment: @hugo oh, the **Map()**! I’ll create another test case then.

Comment: @hugo the way I created the **new Map()** makes it much slower. It makes sense to me, as the code still has to loop over the items (two loops), and also has to create a **Map()** and read from this **Map()**. The simple embedded loop style is the fastest - it uses the most basic JS code elements (no **filter()**, **find()**, **new Map()**, etc), and only loops through the arrays once each (so two loops altogether - with a **break**). https://jsperf.com/filter-or-find-stackoverflow I guess mapping helps you if you have to repeat the process - but if the code runs only once, then it's overkill.

Comment: @muka.gergely It's because the sample is *ridiculously* small. `Map`'s "fixed cost" makes it lose this race, but it wins in the long run. I edited your test, simply adding more elements (100 for both arrays): https://jsperf.com/filter-or-find-stackoverflow/3 (btw thanks for letting me know of this wonderful tool)

Comment: also interesting to see that `for: find()` is now doing better than `for: for: push`

Comment: @hugo a lot things to check - **Object.assign()**, **find()**, **for(i--)**, etc. Even for a simple(-looking) case like this so many things that affect the performance! :) And you're welcome for **jsperf.com** - there are others like this, but I met this first.

Comment: @muka.gergely In general, you should work on significant amounts of data -- with arrays of 2 elements each, the dumbest solution will be the fastest. Now you see that with only 100 elements in each list, the trend has already reversed.

Comment: @hugo I’m quite interested in what does **Map()** do differently - only the indexing? Or maybe it uses an entirely different algorithm? I’ll look into it.

Comment: @muka.gergely [Hash Table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) extremely powerful concept. You don't even need `Map`, a plain JS object is also a hash table of its own!

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `Map` object and store the users indexed by id, so it will be more efficient for later user search

I would do the map/find solution if the user is only needed once and the users array is not that big

```js
const users = [
  {
    id: 33,
    first_name: 'Alex',
    last_name: 'Shelly'
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    first_name: 'Mike',
    last_name: 'Marley'
  }
];

const selectedNotes = [
  {
    employee_id: 33,
    notes: 'test'
  },
  {
    employee_id: 109,
    notes: 'test1'
  }
];

const usersMap = new Map();

for (const user of users) {
  usersMap.set(user.id, user);
}

const selectedNotesWithUser = selectedNotes.map(note => {
  const user = usersMap.get(note.employee_id);

  if (!user) {
    // Do you want to do something if there is no user?
    console.warn(`there is no user for employee id: ${note.employee_id}`);
  }

  return Object.assign(note, user);
});

console.log(selectedNotesWithUser);

// map & find
const selectedNotesWithUser2 = selectedNotes.map(note => {
  const user = users.find(user => user.id === note.employee_id);

  if (!user) {
    // Do you want to do something if there is no user?
    console.warn(`there is no user for employee id: ${note.employee_id}`);
  }

  return Object.assign(note, user);
});

console.log(selectedNotesWithUser2);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick hacky way, and assuming that selectedNodes is subset of Users:

```
const users = [
    {id: 33, first_name: "Alex", last_name: "Shelly"},
    {id: 23, first_name: "Mike", last_name: "Marley"}
]

let selectedNodes = [
    {employee_id: 33, notes: 'test'},
    {employee_id: 34, notes: 'test1'}
]

for (let i = 0; i < selectedNodes.length; i++) {
    const user = users.find(u => u.id===selectedNodes[i].employee_id);
    const name = `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}`;
    selectedNodes[i].by_name = name;
}

console.log(selectedNodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will be accessing the `user` array often then it might be worth transforming it into a `Map` with the `user.id` as the key. That way you would be able to access any given user in `O(1)` time.

```js
const user = [
  { id: 33, first_name: 'Alex', last_name: 'Shelly' },
  { id: 23, first_name: 'Mike', last_name: 'Marley' }
];

const selectedNotes = [
  { employee_id: 33, notes: 'test' },
  { employee_id: 109, notes: 'test1' }
];

const userMap = user.reduce((res, user) => ({...res, [user.id]: user}), {}); // Generate: O(N)

const selectedUser = userMap[selectedNotes[0].employee_id]; // Access/Inser/Delete: O(1)

console.log(selectedUser);
```